# Adding comma between acronym expansion and page number in \printglossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I'm using `glossaries-extra`in the following way: in the preamble of my document I have

```
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,automake]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}
\newacronym{CODL}{CODL}{Concise Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics}
\newacronym{MW}{MW}{Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English}
```

then inside the document I have `\gls{CODL}` and `\gls{MW}` and, finally, at the end of the document,

```
\printglossaries
```

After compiling the file with XeLaTeX, I run `makeglossaries <file-name>`

I get the following:

[image]

and it looks as if the page number is part of the acronym.

How can I get a comma between the acronym expansion and the page number?

Comment: You can modify the glossary style, see chapter 13 of the manual. If you post an MWE someone may look into it for you.